# Redis Server inside Docker Container with nginx + redis_pass

Tags: django, docker, nginx, redis, django-channels

I'm developing a simple Chat application (based on [django-private-chat2](https://github.com/Bearle/django_private_chat2) ) with django & django-channels. I want the application to be fully Containerized and use nginx for routing inside the container.

So I'm trying to connect through a web-socket to a redis-server running inside a docker container. I've tried many things (see below) but still can't get it to work. It is not unlikely that my general approach is wrong.

EDIT:
As @Zeitounator suggested I've created a mcve illustrating the Problem. It's on my secondary github [here](https://github.com/user-1024/django-chat-redis-mcve) it contains **all** configuration files for a minimal example (Dockerfile, docker-compose.yaml, nginx.conf, redis.conf, supervisord.ini ...) also the folder 'tests' contains two tests illustrating - that it works locally, but not inside container. Tests are to be run inside root directory.

> I've added important configs code at the end.

I still believe my nginx configuration might be off, **any** help appreciated!

Here is what I've got so far.

- Redis-Server and websocket connection **works** outside Docker container.
- Inside the docker container I compile and run nginx with the 'HTTP Redis' [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/redis/)
- this module is loaded via 'load_module *.so' inside nginx.conf, I've verified that the module is loaded.
- I've configured the redis-server inside the Docker-container to use 'bind 0.0.0.0 and protected-mode no'
- Inside nginx then I route all the '/' traffic to a django application running on port 8000.
- I route all traffic to 'chat_ws/' ( from the web socket ) to 127.0.0.1:6379 the redis-server ( with nginx reverse_proxy ).
- I've verified that routing works properly ( return 404 with nginx on chat_ws addresses works )
- I can connect to the redis-server through redis-cli on my machine, when I use 'redis-cli -h DOCKER_CONTAINER_IP' so the redis_pass also seems to work.
- In the django settings I've specified the CHANNEL_LAYERS and set the redis backend host to 127.0.0.1:6379 ( which again works completely fine outside the Docker container)
- But if I open the webpage (through the Docker container) in my Browser everything works **except** the websocket connection to the redis-server

I'm especially confused that redis-cli connection to the container works fine but not the websocket, Which **does** work locally ( outside the container ).

( What I've been thinking:

- maybe a web-socket connection w. redis_pass throuh nginx is generally problematic?
- maybe 'HTTP Redis' version is to old, but how to debug this since I don't see any log output of the module in nginx stdout. )

Any help to debug recommendation is appreciated. Or Ideas for different approaches. Also tell me If I should provide further Information or share specific config files. Thanks in advance!

### Dockerfile:

Installs requirements, compiles nginx w. redis_pass, start everything.

```
FROM nginx:alpine AS builder

ADD ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 py3-pip && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN set -ex \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps postgresql-dev build-base python3-dev python2-dev libffi-dev  \
    && python3 -m venv /env \
    && python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python3 -m pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools \
    && python3 -m ensurepip \
    && python3 -m pip install -r /app/requirements.txt \
    && runDeps="$(scanelf --needed --nobanner --recursive /env \
        | awk '{ gsub(/,/, "\nso:", $2); print "so:" $2 }' \
        | sort -u \
        | xargs -r apk info --installed \
        | sort -u)" \
    && apk add --virtual rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

RUN apk add --no-cache build-base libressl-dev libffi-dev 

# rest of code is mounted to the docker container in docker-compose ( only in dev, for local debugging )
WORKDIR /app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Install Supervisord to, start redis-server, gunicorn and nginx simultaniously
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
RUN apk add --no-cache redis

# Stuff needed to make custom nginx compilation
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
  gcc \
  libc-dev \
  make \
  openssl-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  zlib-dev \
  linux-headers \
  curl \
  gnupg \
  libxslt-dev \
  gd-dev \
  geoip-dev

RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O nginx.tar.gz

# compile with HTTP redis for nginx
RUN wget "https://people.freebsd.org/~osa/ngx_http_redis-0.3.9.tar.gz" -O redis.tar.gz

# Compile ...
RUN mkdir /usr/src && \
    CONFARGS=$(nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*arguments: //p') \
    tar -zxC /usr/src -f nginx.tar.gz && \
  tar -xzvf "redis.tar.gz" && \
    REDISDIR="$(pwd)/ngx_http_redis-0.3.9" && \
  cd /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION && \
  ./configure --with-compat $CONFARGS --add-dynamic-module=$REDISDIR && \
  make && make install

COPY supervisord.ini /etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir /etc/redis
COPY ./redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Start all services ( see ./supercisord.ini )
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor.d/supervisord.ini"]
```

### nginx.conf

```
daemon off;
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module /usr/local/nginx/modules/ngx_http_redis_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  access_log /dev/stdout;
  upstream asgi {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen   80;
    server_name localhost;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    location /chat_ws {
        set $redis_key $uri;

        redis_pass     127.0.0.1:6379;
        error_page     404 = /fallback;
    }

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_pass http://asgi;
    }

  }
}
```

### redis.conf

```
bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginxweb:
    image: redis_nginx_docker
    restart: always
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    env_file:
      - env
    volumes:
      - ./mcve:/app
```

Remaining configuration may be found in the git [repo](https://github.com/user-1024/django-chat-redis-mcve).

Comment: Hi and welcome here. Rather than a literary description of what you have done (and possibly you think you have done....), you should post an [mcve](/help/mcve) with all relevant information and resources (Dockerfile,docker-compose.yml, commands you used, errors you get...) As is there are very few chances your question will attract answers because there are too many things people have to guess. Moreover, this type of question might be better suited for https://serverfault.com than SO.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll compile a mcve as soon as possible and will consider serverfault.com next.

Comment: @Zeitounator I've edited the post and added an mcve.

Comment: Please add the code inside the question in code blocks, not in external links. This is a good practice explained in [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)